# Manipulating/Filtering CSV files python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two csv files representing the same data  : `source1.csv` and `source2.csv`

`source1.csv` looks like this:

| id | name | url | link |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | Alex | aaaa | eeee |
| 2222 | Dan | bbbb | ffff |
| 3333 | Jack | cccc | gggg |

`source2.csv` looks like this: (where both columns `url` and `link` are empty)

| location | id | url | name | link |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxxx | 1111 |  | Alex |  |
| xyxy | 9999 |  | George |  |
| zyzy | 8888 |  | Sam |  |
| zzyy | 2222 |  | Dan |  |
| xxyy | 7777 |  | Adam |  |
| xzyz | 3333 |  | Jack |  |

Right now, I want to go over the `source1.csv` file and read the data somehow, then populate the rows in `source2.csv` with corresponding values for the `url` and `link` columns based on the value of the unique field `id`, so that I get something like this:

| location | id | url | name | link |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxxx | 1111 | aaaa | Alex | eeee |
| xyxy | 9999 |  | George |  |
| zyzy | 8888 |  | Sam |  |
| zzyy | 2222 | bbbb | Dan | ffff |
| xxyy | 7777 |  | Adam |  |
| xzyz | 3333 | cccc | Jack | gggg |

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read each file into a dataframe and then merge the relevant columns from each  together using id as the key.

```
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.read_csv('source1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('source2.csv')

print(df1)
print(df2)

df = df2[['location', 'id','name']].merge(df1[['id','url', 'link']], how='left', on='id').fillna(' ')

print(df)
```